# python swig string to char* conversion

Tags: python, c, string, swig

I am working with a project that uses python SWIG module. The module has a function:

```
void func(char* pin, unsigned long len);
```

and is called from python like this:

```
key = "\x42\x1d\xd7"
modul.func(key)
```

The strange thing is that the size of incoming array is 4 instead of 3. The last character (d7) is being converted into two characters (c3 97). I noticed that if the byte has highest bit set, then it expands in two bytes. I suppose this has something to do with string encodings or such.

Is there another way of passing "\x42\x1d\xd7" to SWIG module function?

In another words: I need a way to create a string in python, which is kind of malformed. It needs to have only 3 bytes [0x42, 0x1d, 0xd7]

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to say you want to pass `\x42\x1d\xd7` without it being converted into unicode?

The issue in your case comes because `\x42\x1d\xd7` is converted into 'utf-8' when passing to `modul.func()` .

You can test this by doing -

```
key = "\x42\x1d\xd7"
key.encode('utf-8').decode('unicode-escape')
>> 'B\x1d\xc3\x97'
```

For your issue, you can stop the encoding/decoding of the `key` variable by python, by appending a `r` to the definition of the string as below -

```
key = r"\x42\x1d\xd7"
```

This tells the python interpreter to read the string `raw` . Try that.

Comment: If I use raw, the size of incoming array is 12, it comes with slashes and 'x'-es. I want to get incoming array of size 3. {0x42, 0x1d, 0xd7}

Comment: I also tried to pass key.encode(), but then python complains about types

TypeError: in method 'Module_func', argument 2 of type 'char *'

Comment: Try - `key.encode('utf-8').decode()` , without the `raw`

Comment: key.encode('unicode-escape').decode() without the raw turns into "B\\x1d\\xd7\\x92q" char* string

Comment: Sorry, that was wrong, use the new one , with `utf-8`

Comment: This does not work, produces more different bytes. What I want is to create a string object in python and pass this string to C, but this string must have 3 bytes (0x42, 0x1d, 0xd7)